# Stop pandas from converting floating-point column indices to strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm using `pandas.read_csv` to read a csv file that looks like this (minus formatting)

```
   , 0.1, 0.2
8  , 10,  20
8.1, 11,  22
8.2, 13,  25
```

I read the file by calling

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=0)
```

the resulting dataframe has columns indexed by `'0.1'` and `'0.2'` (i. e. strings) instead of `0.1` and `0.2` (i. e. floats). The row indics are converted to floats.

Why aren't the column indices converted? How can I convert them? (preferably already when I read the file).

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.astype(float)` or `df.columns = pd.to_numeric(df.columns, errors='ignore')`?

Comment: @QuangHoang thank you, the first one works (I didn't try the other one).

Comment: No problem. Note that the other would work better in case you have columns whose names are not `float`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
dataframe.columns = pd.to_numeric(dataframe.columns, errors='ignore')
```